# Passport OIDC Authentication Strategy Problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, openid-connect

I am facing an issue with my OIDC Authentication with Passport. The project is in NodeJS, Typescript.  The infra of the project is microservices with a proxy forwarding the requests to the corresponding microservice. The part of the code that implements the oidc is shown in the code below.

The problem: When is the first time I visit my website (ex incognito) and try to login with the provider, the website redirects me to provider's login page, I add my credentials and then when the provider calls back the `/callback` endpoint I get **"socket hang up"** error and **"did not find expected authorization request details in session"**. In this case I've noticed that the connect.sid is not yet set to my web's cookies before the first attempt. After the first failed attempt, the connect.sid cookie is set and every attempt after that is working properly without any problems.

```
import createMemoryStore from "memorystore";
import {
  Issuer,
  Strategy,
  TokenSet,
  UserinfoResponse,
  custom,
} from "openid-client";
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";

  if (ENABLE_OIDC_LOGIN) {
    custom.setHttpOptionsDefaults({
      timeout: 10000,
    });

    const SECRET = EnvironmentConfig.SESSION_SECRET;
    const MemoryStore = createMemoryStore(session);
    app.use(
      session({
        proxy: true,
        store: new MemoryStore({
          checkPeriod: 86400000,
        }),
        secret: SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
      })
    );

    Issuer.discover(EnvironmentConfig.OIDC_DISCOVER_URL)
      .then((criiptoIssuer) => {
        const client = new criiptoIssuer.Client({
          client_id: EnvironmentConfig.OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: EnvironmentConfig.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET,
          redirect_uris: [
            `${EnvironmentConfig.GATEWAY_BASE_URL}/auth/oidc/callback`,
          ],
          response_types: ["code"],
        });

        passport.use(
          "oidc",
          new Strategy(
            {
              client,
              passReqToCallback: true,
              usePKCE: true,
            },
            createOidcUser(RegistrationType.OIDC)
          )
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("OIDC STRATEGY ERROR", error);
      });
  }
```

Any ideas of what may cause the problem?